# Proper way to write tests in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I followed some tutorials online and found out that tests can be written using `mocha` and i successfully wrote a small one that i found online

```
var assert = require('assert');
describe('Array', function() {
  describe('#indexOf()', function() {
    it('should return -1 when the value is not present', function() {
      assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(4));
    });
  });
});
```

Now after this i moved on to testing it with `expressjs` application. I am not sure on how to write proper tests on it.

Currently i need to manually run the server in one window and run tests in another. Also another setback is the database, every time i run those tests, i need the data to be deleted by default, that is use a separate database for tests and delete the contents after finished.

Because most of the code is restfull api, i am using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to actually make the requests.

Would really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction so i don't have to manually start the server and clear database just for running test.

> The express application is generated using `express-generator` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

export your express app, then require it in the test and wrap it in your sender. I'm not that familiar with request, but i believe that chai-http or supertest can do something like that. It will also allow you to run this code through code-coverage tool like NYC.

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import request from 'supertest';
import server from '../../server/server';

describe('Test server', () => {
  describe('Fetch component', () => {
    it('Dont find route - return 404', done => {
      request(server)
        .get('/randomlocation')
        .expect(404, done);
    });
    it('Return component', (done) => {
      request(server)
        .get('/login')
        .expect(200, done);
    });
  });
});
```